# OOP design : avoiding state and keeping dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have a class that need to be initialized and only then can start working. However , I don't want to create it inside my object , I want it to be injected - So I need to have both init() and run().

This , however , create a problem - The object now has state , and I'm trying to avoid it. Is there a design pattern to overcome this situation?

Comment: Any object-oriented design is necessarily stateful unless none of your classes have any global variables and all local variables are declared 'final'.

Comment: @Travis That's a good point , but I didn't mean it in the fundamental way you describe - I meant that it's more like a state machine - you can't do B without doing A , and it's something I find hard to inforce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On Dependency Injection:**
Dependency Injection is just a fancy term for passing in an implementation of logic into a class. The most basic form of dependency injection is the `constructor`. You just pass in an instance of whatever you don't want to be inside the class, as a parameter to the constructor.

```
public interface Logic
{
    public void do();
}

public class MyClass
{
    private final Logic logic;

    public MyClass(final Logic logic)
    {
        this.logic = logic;
    }

    public void doLogic() { this.logic.do(); }
}

public class MyLogic implements Logic
{
   public void do() { /* custom logic goes here */ }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final MyClass myClass = new MyClass(new MyLogic());
        myClass.doLogic();
    }
}
```

**Building Classes:**
A good way to ensure that the class is constructed fully and initialized is a `FactoryMethod` pattern. Create a `static MyClass create();` method and make the `MyClass` constructors `private` and that initializes your class and makes sure it is valid before passing it out.

```
public class MyClass
{
    /** Factory Method, only way to create a MyClass instance */
    public static MyClass create()
    {
        final MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        // initialize class however you need it
        return instance;
    }

    private MyClass()
    {
        // normal constructor, if no logic you still need this
        // to make sure it can only be created by the Factory Method
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution , but it doesn't solve the entire problem - I want to class A to be created outside of class B , and then passed to B in the constructor - but Class A still need to be initialized within class B (only he knows the needed values).

Comment: **No offense but that is a really poor design.** What is the point of creating a Class that can't be used unless configured by another class? That breaks all kinds of best practices rules of OOA/OOD. A better design would be to have Class A would be a Public inner class of Class B. Thus Class B can control the instantiation and configuration of all Class A instances. What you are describing is another use for the FactoryPattern. If you need multiple different implementations of Class A, then have a common Interface and have all the Implemenations inner classes of Class B.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance it sounds like you should provide your dependency as a constructor argument. This gives you the added safety of attaching the `final` keyword so you can ensure it never gets set again.